# Language Agonostic - Getting all coordinates within a rectangle

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, geometry, coordinates

So let's say I have a rectangle, 10px by 10px, with the coordinates of the top left corner at 0, 0(those numbers are arbitrary and just an example). Below is a picture of such, with every box being one pixel and the green part being the rectangle in question.

[image]

If I wanted to get a list of every coordinate inside that rectangle, how would that be done? With this rectangle in particular, it would be a list of 100 coordinates. Please tell me if the question is not clear enough.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the smaller rectangles have the same size then you can use the dimensions of the rectangles  to come up with the coordinates. 
For example, if the size of rectangle is 1*1 and the green area has only one rectangle then coordinates will be (0,0) , (0,1), (1,0) and (1,1)

If the green area has four sub rectangles in the same example then coordinates will be (0,0) , (0,1), (1,0) ,(1,1) , (2,0), (2,1) (1,2), (2,2)

You can generalize this approach

Answer (score 0):

Turns out with some hard thinking(I am rather unexperienced in geometry) I was able to solve this myself. In JS:

```
function getRectCoordinates(x, y, width, height) {
    var coordinates = [];

    for (var h = 0; h < height; h++) {
        for (var w = 0; w < width; w++) {
            coordinates.push({x: w + x, y: h + y});
        };
    };

    return coordinates;
}
```